# Google Compute engine instance all Ports are busy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, connection, port, google-compute-engine

I want to connect my instance with another instance through sockets and i can choose the port on which my instance build up the connection. It does not matter what port i take between 1024 and 65535, i get the information that the port is busy and i should choose another port.
Does somebody know what to do ?
If i take the internal ip address, it works, but the other instance can not contact my instance.

Answer (score 1):

First, You can check your VM instance if there’s an active firewall.

For Debian/Ubuntu you can run the command:
‘sudo ufw status’

For Centos/Redhat you can run the command:
‘sudo firewall-cmd --state’

Basically if there are no active firewalls inside your two VM instances and within the same VPC it should be able to connect to each other.

In addition, you can install “Nmap” to scan the open ports to the other VM instance.